# Storybook: How to force Storybook to NOT create a folder for my component

Tags: storybook

For all my other components, Storybook shows the story directly (there is no subfolder). But in my component called "IconButton", it creates a subfolder and then shows the actual file. How can I make it not show a folder?

All my other files look like this

```js
import React from "react";
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react";

import { IconButton } from "./IconButton";
import { IconButtonDemo } from "./IconButton.demo";

export default {
    title: "Atoms/IconButton",
    component: IconButton,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof IconButton>;

const IconButtonComponentStory: ComponentStory<typeof IconButton> = () => <IconButtonDemo />;

export const _IconButton = IconButtonComponentStory.bind({});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happpening because story names are start cased automatically. So the name **IconButton** that you intent to give as name for your story becomes **Icon Button** when rendered.

The solution is to set a Story name manuly and make it match the Component name.

_IconButton.storyName = "IconButton";

should fix your problem;

Answer (score 0):

If the `title` prop in `<Meta>` coincides with the `name` prop provided for `<Story>`, it won't create a supplementary directory around the story:

```
<Meta 
    title="Notifications/Success Notification" 
    component={SuccessNotification}
/>

<Preview>
    <Story
        name='Success Notification'
        // props etc.>            
        {(args) => {return (<SuccessNotification {...args}/>)}}
    </Story>
</Preview>
```

[image]